# Why ng-include causing $digest iterations reached?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

Receiving data by

```
$scope.$watch("build.idx", ->
  $http.get("/build/" + $scope.build.idx + ".json").success((data) ->
    $scope.build = data
  )
)
```

ng-include inside ng-repeat

```
.build-stage
  .row{ "ng-repeat" => "stage in build.stages" }
    %div{ "ng-include" => "donoting.html" } # donoting.html is blank
```

first loading page, it's OK. and when changing build.idx, it cause

```
10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: function (){var a=d.url(),b=h.$$replace;p&&a==h.absUrl()||(p++,c.$evalAsync(function(){c.$broadcast(\"$locationChangeStart\",h.absUrl(),a).defaultPrevented?h.$$parse(a):(d.url(h.absUrl(),b),g(a))}));h.$$replace=!1;return p}; newVal: 8; oldVal: 7"],["fn: function (){var a=d.url(),b=h.$$replace;p&&a==h.absUrl()||(p++,c.$evalAsync(function(){c.$broadcast(\"$locationChangeStart\",h.absUrl(),a).defaultPrevented?h.$$parse(a):(d.url(h.absUrl(),b),g(a))}));h.$$replace=!1;return p}; newVal: 9; oldVal: 8"],["fn: function (){var a=d.url(),b=h.$$replace;p&&a==h.absUrl()||(p++,c.$evalAsync(function(){c.$broadcast(\"$locationChangeStart\",h.absUrl(),a).defaultPrevented?h.$$parse(a):(d.url(h.absUrl(),b),g(a))}));h.$$replace=!1;return p}; newVal: 10; oldVal: 9"],["fn: function (){var a=d.url(),b=h.$$replace;p&&a==h.absUrl()||(p++,c.$evalAsync(function(){c.$broadcast(\"$locationChangeStart\",h.absUrl(),a).defaultPrevented?h.$$parse(a):(d.url(h.absUrl(),b),g(a))}));h.$$replace=!1;return p}; newVal: 11; oldVal: 10"],["fn: function (){var a=d.url(),b=h.$$replace;p&&a==h.absUrl()||(p++,c.$evalAsync(function(){c.$broadcast(\"$locationChangeStart\",h.absUrl(),a).defaultPrevented?h.$$parse(a):(d.url(h.absUrl(),b),g(a))}));h.$$replace=!1;return p}; newVal: 12; oldVal: 11"]]
```

and when removing ng-include line, it's OK.
I think it's ng-include causes $locationChangeStart fired, but why?

Comment: What is with the syntax of the template you are using? I've never seen it before. The .build-stage part

Comment: haml, a kind of server template

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting :)

Comment: The error is caused by other action.(pushState)

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that the path of the template to include in ng-include is correct. If not it causes the `10 $digest() iterations reached` error.

If the path is not correct the server will serve the index.html (at least in the case you use html5 mode the server defaults to serve index.html); the index.html will be included and will cause the ng-include directive to run again; the result is an an infinite loop of iteratively included index.html which is terminated with the error message `10 $digest() iterations reached`

Answer (score 0):

you got your self in a infinite loop right here

```
$scope.$watch("build.idx", ->
  $http.get("/build/" + $scope.build.idx + ".json").success((data) ->
    $scope.build = data
  )
)
```

you are watching for build.idx, and if that changes requesting information that will change build which will trigger the request again and again modify the build variable andf go on and on and this will quicly reflect in the digest cycle by constantly changing and angular will throw this exception, because it detected a possible infinite loop

Comment: ng-include will change requesting information? and why changing the build?
how to solve it? thx a lot!

Comment: ng-include is not the problem, the peace of code i posted is, you can't watch on something your watcher is going to modify.

Comment: i m sure it is ng-include trigger that, as i said before it's ok when just removing the ng-include

Comment: n i watched build.idx not build,

Comment: if you change build what would happens to build.idx?

Comment: The idx of build in response is same as build.idx. in other way the error disappeared if ng-include removed

Comment: even if I renamed build.idx as buildIdx, the error still happened

Comment: actually, I think it's ng-include causes $locationChangeStart fired, but why?

Comment: you renamed it where? in the watcher? lets do this, comment the entire watcher and provide a mock of your build object and lets see if you still get this error, when build is not changing

Comment: makes no sense ng-include doesn't affect location

Comment: sorry, it is caused by the other action(pushState for changing url without reloading). The question will be closed.